# Issue trying to connect Azure CDN endpoint with custom origin (origin pointing to Azure Function App Proxy)

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-cdn, azure-function-app-proxy

I have a static website hosted in a storage account, and i want to be able to manage the request/response headers. I found some sources about people that used Function App Proxy as a workaround. And it all works well. But i am using Azure CDN to cache the website and deliver it. So i tried to create a CDN endpoint, using custom origin, and connect it to the Function App Proxy. But the CDN is not able to pull and cache the content. Any idea if this anyhow is possible to work? I definitely need the CDN in front of the website, in order to achieve better performance.